# android: how to make sure i posted correctly using httppost

Tags: android, web-services, http-post

I have a web address www.abc.com/check ... I have created a web service on this address for receiving data. Through an android app i send some data to this address using following code:

```
public class TestappActivity extends Activity {
    EditText ch;
    Button btn;
    InputStream is;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ch);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            sendData();

            }
        });


    }


    private void sendData() {

          Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");

            HttpParams p=new BasicHttpParams();
            p.setParameter("name", ch.getText());


          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(p);


          try {
                HttpResponse response=client.execute(new HttpPost("http://www.abc.com/check"));
                is=response.getEntity().getContent();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }



          Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - end");

        }
}
```

How can i find if my post was successful ? What do i get back when i post something. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[update]Simple solution, you can just check the status code

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

It's a integer(200 means OK, 500 means error on server) , [Reference Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)

Or a completely check by using the response body

```
response.getEntity().getContent();
```

It is generated on the server by your service,  so if you want to assure the invocation is really successful, you can return something to client. e.g.  a XML string

```
"<status>OK</status>"
```

in the response body would be enough.  You will get it on client and then do whatever you want to do.

I recommend the simpler solution.  Thanks shraddha

Answer (score 0):

I guess baoz is right, but there is one simple alternative to this.

```
response.getStatusLine.getstatuscode(); //200-successful
```

It will return numeric response code for success as well as error. Moreover, if the response is negative, it will return you relevant error code so that you can track and catch those errors.

Regards.